# Encrypt/Decrypt data in Vb.net and SQL Server

Tags: vb.net, encryption, sql-server-2008-r2

I currently use two functions, in a VB.net application, to encrypt/decrypt sensitive data (e.g. SSNs). I then store the encrypted data in a SQL Server database. Then, when reading data from SQL Server, the application decrypts it for display. This works just fine.

The problem with this solution is that it makes it impossible to write simple SQL queries that include those encrypted fields as the data that comes back is encrypted. I want to be able to run queries that return the data that was stored in encrypted format, in its original format (i.e. the actual, unencrypted data).

What is the best practice for accomplishing this? Should I not be using functions in the VB.net application, but rather using functions in SQL Server, for example? Or, do  I need to create a DLL or something that has the two aforementioned functions that I then need to "install" somehow, so that they can be called from SQL Server? I am using SQL Server 2008 and Visual Studio 2017.

In case it's relevant, I have included the code for the functions.

```
Private key() As Byte = {}
Private IV() As Byte = {&H12, &H34, &H56, &H78, &H90, &HAB, &HCD, &HEF}

Public Function Decrypt(ByVal sStringToDecrypt As String, _
ByVal sEncryptionKey As String) As String
  Dim inputByteArray(sStringToDecrypt.Length) As Byte
  Try
    key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Left(sEncryptionKey, 8))
    Dim des As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()
    inputByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(sStringToDecrypt)
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
    Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(key, IV), _
        CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length)
    cs.FlushFinalBlock()
    Dim encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    Return encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray())
  Catch ex As Exception
    Return ex.Message
  End Try
End Function

Public Function Encrypt(ByVal sStringToEncrypt As String, _
    ByVal SEncryptionKey As String) As String
  Try
    key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Left(SEncryptionKey, 8))
    Dim des As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim inputByteArray() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( _
        sStringToEncrypt)
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
    Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(key, IV), _
        CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length)
    cs.FlushFinalBlock()
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
  Catch ex As Exception
    Return ex.Message
  End Try
End Function
```

Comment: `"The problem with this solution is that it makes it impossible to write simple SQL queries that include those encrypted fields as the data that comes back is encrypted."` I don't see this as a problem, rather as a benefit. No one should be running "simple" queries to access such sensitive information such as SSNs in this day and age. Your access to unencrypted SSNs should be controlled, on a strictly as-needed basis, and not in bulk. Data privacy laws are becoming more and more strict in the US as well as world-wide.

Comment: I am the database administrator and need to run queries to provide data to the client. The Windows Forms application that I wrote uses the data and even displays it in decrypted format, on certain forms. They have the legal right to view and use the data, in the relationships that they have with their "customers." I am just looking for an easier way to accomplish the above.

Comment: Understood, but even you as the DBA shouldn't have access to unencrypted sensitive, personally identifiable information such as SSNs. If clients require queries, you should build secure reports, where they can access the data. I've done this before, and used Telerik Reporting, since it made it easy to decrypt the incoming data source via .NET code. My point is, accessing this kind of sensitive data isn't - and shouldn't be - trivial.

Comment: When it is all said and done, I am the one that is writing the query and/or the code that gives them the data that they need. It is not about trivial or difficult, for me. It's about doing things in a way that is efficient for me. If I could write queries that use the same secure .Net code that I use in the application, for reports, etc., that would be ideal. Or, perhaps the solution is to modify the application to use some functions in SQL Server to encrypt and decrypt the data.